# Bot Framework Adaptive Dialogs. How can I change the Generator(.lg file)?

Tags: c#, botframework, multilingual, adaptive-dialogs

I need to change the .lg file for multilingual support. The dialogues are written also in .dialog format.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeESE.png)

Comment: please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-multiple-language